# How to hide dynamic content using jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using a service for autocompleting my search boxes. However, for all the autocompleted results that show up, there's always a `<div>` ad on the bottom following the `<li>`s. Something like this:

```
<ul>
<li class="menu-item""></li>
<li class="menu-item""></li>
<li class="menu-item""></li>
<div style="text-align:center;border-top:1px solid black;"></div>
<a href="http://www.ad.com" target="_blank">ad</a>
</ul>
```

However, this is loaded dynamically using JS so I don't know how I would write jQuery to `hide()` it. Is there a way I could dynamically hide it when someone does a search?

Comment: For starters, your HTML is invalid.

Comment: sorry I forgot to paste the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this in your CSS:

```
ul>* {display:none}
ul>li {display:block}
```

After all, it is only valid for `<ul>` elements to have `<li>` children, so you should be able to hide everything else as invalid.

Comment: will this work for nodes that are not present in the initial load of the DOM? the li's and div are generated dynamically when someone types a search term, so it doesn't exist in the initial load

Comment: @Edmund yes, it will be applied as and when the nodes load on page.

Comment: is there a way to make this CSS line load after all the other CSS files in this app? my line is being overridden by the Ad company's CSS.

Comment: Add `!important` before each `}` to make it override the ad company's CSS. Or you could just find a solution that doesn't involve an ad ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of the structure, you can always address it in jquery as

```
$("ul").find("a,div").hide()
```

---

Best would be of course css, as Kolink answered.